# how do you create a custom function in Sass (not SCSS)

Tags: sass

Lots of documentation on doing this in SCSS..

```
@function _em($wanted, $inherited) {
  @return ($wanted / $inherited) + 'em';
}
```

How would you go about this in Sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@function _em()
  @return ($wanted / $inherited) + 'em'
```

Just remove the brackets and semicolons.

Comment: Also, if you want the output to not be a string, use `* 1em` instead of `+ 'em'`. That will give you `5em` rather than `"5em"`.